# Wordpress filter user_row_actions

Tags: wordpress

Am trying to add a link besides the Edit | Delete links in wordpress admin > users > all users list through a plugin.. this is my first attempt at making a wordpress plugin by looking at other plugins or search google..

I have added a function

```
function pa_user_list_pay_link( $actions, $user_object ) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'administrator', $user_object->ID ) )
        $actions['pay'] = '<a href="#">Pay</a>';
    return $actions;
}
```

and the applied the filter

```
add_filter( 'user_row_actions', array( $this, 'pa_user_list_pay_link' ), 10, 2 );
```

But something seems to go wrong as this link is not appearing and the Edit | Delete links also disappear (no longer in the html output)

UPDATE 1 :
I modified /wp-admin/includes/class-wp-users-list-table.php

After this line

```
$actions = apply_filters( 'user_row_actions', $actions, $user_object );
```

I added this

```
file_put_contents("test_output.txt" , count($actions));
```

the test_output.txt was written to /wp-admin/
and it contained **0**

I think i am doing some mistake in applying the filter..

Update 2: Answered my own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function pa_user_list_pay_link( $actions, $user_object ) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'administrator', $user_object->ID ) )
        $actions['pay'] = '<a href="#">Pay</a>';
    return $actions;
}

add_filter( 'user_row_actions', 'pa_user_list_pay_link', 10, 2 );
```

Works! :D

Comment: Ah - so your `add_filter` wasn't being called from inside a class?

Comment: No, am very new to plugin writing so wanted to keep it as simple as possible.. whats the benefit of having everything inside a class in a wordpress plugin?

Answer (score 1):

If the edit / delete links are disappearing, that'd imply your function's being called, but causing an error.

The first thing I wonder looking at your code is whether `$actions` is an associative array.  Does it work if you change

```
$actions['pay'] = '<a href="#">Pay</a>';
```

to

```
$actions[] = '<a href="#">Pay</a>';
```

?

If that works, you can look at inserting it into the right position, rather than appending.

Just for testing purposes, I'd comment out the `if` statement too, to eliminate permissions as a cause of the error (i.e. try to work out why edit/delete are disappearing before adding too much other logic).

Answer (score -1):

I think there is best way to do it.you can customize Edit and Delete or Add new badge by using add_action('user_row_actions','your_function_name') . for more details you can visit the site where i found the best solution..See this post  [Add or edit custom link in wp users list in wordpress admin](http://darkphp.blogspot.in/2014/05/add-or-edit-custom-link-in-wp-users.html)

Hope it will help you..